# Does "tangible to share" need punctuation?

Tags: commas

Does this sentence need punctuation after "tangible"? I think "tangible to share and inspire" sounds strange, but I'm not sure. I think it may need an em dash or a comma.

> Make your ideas tangible to share and inspire.

Comment: Depends on what you mean. Should the ideas be tangible to share and tangible to inspire (whatever that means exactly)? Or should you make them tangible in order to share and inspire (whatever that means exactly)? I think the reason you think it sounds strange is that the statement doesn't really make much logical sense (barring further context which may make it more obvious what it's supposed to mean).

Comment: Tangible means touchable. I guess a touchable idea could make sense in the right context, but by itself it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a comma:
tangible modifies ideas

> To share and inspire, make your ideas tangible =
>
> Make your ideas tangible, to share and inspire.

without a comma:

> Make your ideas tangible to share and tangible to inspire =
>
> Make your ideas tangible to share and inspire.

tangible to share would modify how something could be shared 
(because of the infinitive use it would essentially be like tangibly)

> [tangibly, adverb](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tangibly)   from dictionary.com
>
> Examples from the Web for tangible
>
> Contemporary Examples
>
> *What happened was, [plastic surgery] was the one thing I did that I felt like I could tangibly grasp onto.*
>
> Meet Justin Jedlica, the Real Life Ken Doll 
>   Erin Cunningham 
>   April 14, 2014
>
> *What comes across most tangibly from Abdi is a sense of delicious disbelief, to suddenly find himself where he is.*